# Object reference required for non static field within same class

Tags: c#

In the same class, I have :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
// event handler
private static void messageReceived (object sender, messageReceivedEvent args)
 {
  //some code
  stopProcesses()
 }
 void stopProcesses()
 {
  //some code
 }
}
```

In the event handler, the call to stopProcesses() give the error in the title : an object reference is required for the non static field, method or property 'MainWindow.stopProcesses'.
They're in the same class, and I can't have stopProcesses as static because I'd have to have every variable and every method if the class as static and that's not the point. 
I don't know how to call the non static method from a static event handler though, what's an object reference to the method ?

Comment: Why cant you make `messageReceived` an instance method too?

Comment: Do you really need the `messageReceived` to be static? Make it an instance method (i.e. remove `static`) and the error will go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is to make `messageReceived` instance scoped instead of static.

```
private void messageReceived (object sender, messageReceivedEvent args) {}
```

If you want to keep it static then you have to use the `sender` instance which should be a reference back to your `MainWindow` instance, all you have to do is cast it.

```
private static void messageReceived (object sender, messageReceivedEvent args)
{
  ((MainWindow)sender).stopProcesses();
}
```